# How to merge duplicated Json objects into one?

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist

I have my `json` like below

```
[{
    "attributeId": 6,
    "attributeType": "price",
    "attributeValue": "{10,20,100}",
    "displayOn": "true",
    "attributeName": "price"
  },
  {
    "attributeId": 6,
    "attributeType": "price",
    "attributeName": "price",
    "displayOn": "true",
    "attributeValue": "{21,40,200}"
  }
]
```

I want to merge into the single one without duplicate like

```
[{
  "attributeId": 6,
  "attributeType": "price",
  "attributeValue": "{10,20,100}",
  "displayOn": "true",
  "attributeName": "price",
  "attributeValue": "{21,40,200}"
}]
```

I tried `extend` and `concat` function. But, I am not able to figure out the correct way to do it. Please help me on this.

Comment: Will the JSON always have an array with two "objects"?

Comment: No ..It wil have more than two also

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want the objects that are later in the array to overwrite object values earlier in the array, you could `reduce` the array and copy each old object into the new one:

```
var arr = [{...}, {...}];

var merged = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
    for (var key in a) {
        a[key] = b[key];
    }
    return a;
});
```

This is cleaned up considerably using ES6 syntax and features:

```
let arr = [{...}, {...}];

let merged = arr.reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(b, a));
```

Note that in your example, the array entities are not JSON strings but parsed objects. If you first need to parse JSON strings into objects, you would need to do that before reducing the array.

Also not that an object cannot have the same property key twice, as you have with `attributeValue`. If this value needs to be preserved, you'll need some other method of doing so.